# Issue inserting values in a loop (for) in the database : same value is inserted - node js / sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I try to insert some data into a database inside a loop. The issue is that it inserts always the same value (the first one). I mean even if the value of my variable is different (I display it on the console so I can check that everything is ok before querying the database to insert it).

My program is based on Node.js.

Here is an example of my code :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result.body);
global.store_urls = [];

for (let i = 0; obj.productEntities.length > i; i++){

   global.store_urls.push(obj.productEntities[i].url);
   var reference=obj.productEntities[i].IdProduct;
   var brand=obj.productEntities[i].Brand;
   var price=obj.productEntities[i].Price;
   var new_price=obj.productEntities[i].PriceNew;
   var reduction=obj.productEntities[i].sale_state;
   var type_1=obj.productEntities[i].Category;
   var sold=obj.productEntities[i].sold;

   console.log(reference+" / "+brand+" / "+price+" / "+new_price+" / "+reduction+" / "+type_1+" / "+sold);

   //Row (data) insertion part
   var sql = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM vd_tendance WHERE url=?", [obj.productEntities[i].url]);
   var selectUrl = connection.query(sql, function(err,rows,fields) {

    if(err){throw err;}
    //Checking the value exist on the table
    if(rows.length > 0){
     //If already exists, no need to insert
      console.log(rows.length);
    }else{
     //Save to database
     connection.query('INSERT INTO `vd_tendance` VALUES ( NULL , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())',
                  [ reference,
                    type_1,
                    brand,
                    price,
                    new_price,
                    reduction,
                    sold,
                    url,
                  ]
              , function (err, result) {
                  if (err) {console.error('error inserting into database : ' + err.stack); return;}
                  else{}
              });
            }
          });


      }
```

The result is always the same data inserted on each row (the first value that variables have taken).

Could you give me few ideas to solve that ? Maybe it's totally related to the asynchronous node js system ?

Thank you all !

Comment: The first value ? Don't you mean the last ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It is the last and not the first. I will edit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop completely executes before the callbacks given to the asynchronous functions are called.

A solution is to trap the array items in a closure, for exemple using forEach:

```
obj.productEntities.forEach(function(entity){
    global.store_urls.push(entity.url);
    var reference = entity.IdProduct;
    ...
```

Note also that the whole loop is still executed before the queries are made, which might be a problem if the code that follows depends on the DB being updated. In such a case you'd better have a look at modern solutions for handling asynchronous tasks:

- [promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html) ([an example of packaged use for mysql](https://github.com/lukeb-uk/node-promise-mysql))
- [async/await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) (not to be confused with the obsolete async module you could get with `require('async')`)

Comment: Thank you , let's try it :)

Comment: It works , thank you for your help again. Both solutions !

Answer (score 0):

Exactly its due to async nature. For loop will be executed Async.

So try the following:

```
    var obj = JSON.parse(result.body);
    global.store_urls = [];
var async = require('async');

    async.forEach(obj.productEntities, function(callback){
   // do your logic
  In this part 

connection.query('INSERT INTO `vd_tendance` VALUES ( NULL , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())',
                  [ reference,
                    type_1,
                    brand,
                    price,
                    new_price,
                    reduction,
                    sold,
                    url,
                  ]
              , function (err, result) {
                  if (err) {console.error('error inserting into database : ' + err.stack); return;}
                  else{
                     callback() ---------------------->Iterate the loop
                  }
              });
            }
          });


   )};
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try now !