# Node.js puppeteer mysql - Inserting fetched values in database inside a loop using mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, puppeteer, node-mysql

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data. ... now I want to insert the fetched data in a databases ... using mysql. The below seems to work ... yet what confuses me is that in the console.log('DB insert successful. Record: '+i); is always behind and after some time it stops ... although there are still tables with records available.

That's my app:

```
  let tableCell01;
  let tableCell01Val;
  let tableCell02;
  let tableCell02Val;

  const tableRows = await page.$$('table.tableFile2 > tbody > tr');

  for (let i=1; i < tableRows.length; i++){

    tableRow = tableRows[i];
    tableCell01 = await tableRow.$('td:nth-child(1) a');
    tableCell01Val = await page.evaluate( tableCell01 => tableCell01.innerText, tableCell01 );
    tableCell02 = await tableRow.$('td:nth-child(2)');
    tableCell02Val = await page.evaluate( tableCell02 => tableCell02.innerText, tableCell02 );

    tableCell02ValA.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');

    console.log('\n');
    console.log('ID: '+tableCell01Val);
    console.log('Company: '+tableCell02Val);
    console.log('Iterator: '+i);

    const insertCompanyList = "INSERT INTO companyList ( company_name, id ) values (?,?)";

    connection.query(insertCompanyList,[tableCell02Val, tableCell01Val],function(err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('DB insert successful. Record: '+i);
      }
    });

  }
```

This I can see in the console:

```
ID: 3136
Company: Company A
Iterator: 1

ID: 3143
Company: Company B
Iterator: 2
DB insert successful. Record: 1

ID: 4497
Company: Company C
Iterator: 3

ID: 3164
Company: Company D
Iterator: 4

ID: 3219
Company: Company E
Iterator: 5

ID: 3071
Company: Company F
Iterator: 6

ID: 3184
Company: Company G
Iterator: 7
DB insert successful. Record: 2

ID: 3130
Company: Company H
Iterator: 8
DB insert successful. Record: 3
DB insert successful. Record: 4
DB insert successful. Record: 5
DB insert successful. Record: 6
DB insert successful. Record: 7
DB insert successful. Record: 8        

ID: 1844
Company: Company I
Iterator: 1

ID: 3687
Company: Company J
Iterator: 2

ID: 4514
Company: ECompany K
Iterator: 3

ID: 3635
Company: Company L
Iterator: 4

ID: 3884
Company: Company M
Iterator: 5

ID: 3482
Company: Company N
Iterator: 6
DB insert successful. Record: 1

ID: 3482
Company: Company O
Iterator: 7

ID: 1827
Company: Company P
Iterator: 8
DB insert successful. Record: 2

ID: 1827
Company: Company Q
Iterator: 9

ID: 6465
Company: Company R
Iterator: 10

ID: 0731
Company: Company S
Country: B9
Iterator: 11
No pagination!
DB insert successful. Record: 3
DB insert successful. Record: 4
DB insert successful. Record: 5
DB insert successful. Record: 6
DB insert successful. Record: 7
DB insert successful. Record: 8
DB insert successful. Record: 9
DB insert successful. Record: 10
DB insert successful. Record: 11
```

What am I missing? I guess I need to put the connection query in a async.function?! Like here: [Issue inserting values in a loop (for) in the database : same value is inserted - node js / sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844755/issue-inserting-values-in-a-loop-for-in-the-database-same-value-is-inserted).?

Comment: You just need to promisify connection.query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just promisify connection.query so you can `await` it. The link to the other question you posted is very similar to your problem.

This question is asked over and over, because it is hard to understand, but basically `connection.query` runs immediately, skips to the next line and then some point later (when the database responds and the event loop has time to process it) the `function(err, rows) {}` parts runs. So in-between some of your pupeteer awaits (or other async processes), it's processing the `function(err,rows){}`.

Next suggestion: learn to use `util.promisify`! (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

```
  let tableCell01;
  let tableCell01Val;
  let tableCell02;
  let tableCell02Val;

  const tableRows = await page.$$('table.tableFile2 > tbody > tr');

  for (let i=1; i < tableRows.length; i++){

    tableRow = tableRows[i];
    tableCell01 = await tableRow.$('td:nth-child(1) a');
    tableCell01Val = await page.evaluate( tableCell01 => tableCell01.innerText, tableCell01 );
    tableCell02 = await tableRow.$('td:nth-child(2)');
    tableCell02Val = await page.evaluate( tableCell02 => tableCell02.innerText, tableCell02 );

    tableCell02ValA.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');

    console.log('\n');
    console.log('ID: '+tableCell01Val);
    console.log('Company: '+tableCell02Val);
    console.log('Iterator: '+i);

    const insertCompanyList = "INSERT INTO companyList ( company_name, id ) values (?,?)";

    let rows = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      connection.query(insertCompanyList,[tableCell02Val, tableCell01Val],function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log('DB insert successful. Record: '+i);
          resolve(rows);
        }
      });
    });

  }
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks ... I'll take a look into util.promisify :-)